# Soil hygrometer without adc

Tags: raspbian, gpio, sensor

I want to measure soil moisture using [THIS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AYCNEKW) sensor. I do  not want to use ADC. In the sensor there is a digital output port and an analogue output port. I can use the digital output of the sensor without using adc? Is there any other way to get soil moisture with this sensor without using ADC[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use the adc? Did you use all of the adc pins already?

Comment: I don't have a adc with me.@portforwardpodcast

Comment: Well you will need to make some sort of circuit to read this. An adc is best. Or even a microcontroller with an internal adc. But the pi doesn't have one.

Comment: Get the datasheet and post it here. Email the guy http://www.amazon.com/Happy-Store-Hygrometer-Detection-Moisture/dp/B00CNFLSZG#productDescription_secondary_view_pageState_1428747355399

Comment: @portforwardpodcast The circuit link did not appear in comment. Can you please post the link

Comment: I was talking about pawel's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, to measure analog value you need some kind of ADC.

Maybe smth like that: http://www.doctormonk.com/2013/12/analog-sensors-without-analog-inputs-on.html

I have not tested it but should work. On the other hand it might be simpler just to use

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/08/reading-analogue-sensors-with-one-gpio-pin/

Answer (score 2):

The digital output will tell you when the set threshold has been exceeded.  You set the threshold with a screwdriver and the blue pot on the board.

It's simplest if you power the device from 3V3.  If you need to power from 5V you will need to add a [voltage divider](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers) on the digital output to shift it from 5V to 3V3.

Answer (score 0):

This module here can add ADC to the Raspberry Pi. It also has Analogue outputs.
http://www.sf-innovations.co.uk/custard-pi-2.html

Comment: Please could you add some more detail to your answer, link only answers are not preferable.